# What does this civirule error message mean? Not a valid action, action class is missing

Tags: civirules

I'm trying to add a rule that will send an email after a profile form is completed.  The trigger is Added to a Group.  The condition is the group created by the profile form.  When I try and select send e-mail for the action, I get this error message. "Not a valid action, action class is missing"  Using WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Send Email action is not present, did you install the Email API extension (https://civicrm.org/extensions/e-mail-api)? This enables the Send Email action.

If you did, can you check if the action is actually in your database? The table is civirule_action.

Comment: That was it!  The extension has been disabled.  Thank you.

Comment: Glad it works again :-)